# NSMutableArray's count method throws an exception when called in expression

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray, nsarray

```
 if ([diamonds count] == 0) {
    [self toggleWinLevel];
}
```

When diamonds is an NSMutableArray and toggleWinLevel is an instance method, if I run this app it crashes on this line with an EXC_BAD_ACCESS:

```
 if ([diamonds count] == 0) {
```

It is is definitely to do with my array since this keeps on happening even when i assign an int or NSUInteger or NSNumber to my array's count. My NSMutableArray is allocated and initialized. What is the problem?

UPDATE 1:

Ive allocated and initialized it in this method which DOES get called and i have NSLog which does log in the console for proof:

```
    -(void)setUpObjects {

NSLog(@"Setting Up Objects"); // This is printed in my console

[levelNumberLabel setHidden:YES];
diamonds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
rocks = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

if (levelNumber < 3) {

    diamonds = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", nil];

} else if (levelNumber > 2 <= 4) {

    diamonds = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", nil];

} else if (levelNumber > 4 <= 6) {

    diamonds = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", nil];

} else if (levelNumber > 6 <= 10) {

    diamonds = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5", nil];

} else if (levelNumber > 10) {

    diamonds = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5", @"6", nil];
}

if ([diamonds count] > 1 <= 2) {

    rocks = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", nil];                 

} else if ([diamonds count] > 2 <= 5) {

    rocks = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", nil];

} else if ([diamonds count] > 5) {

    rocks = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", nil];
}

[self drawObjects];
}
```

BTW diamonds (the array) is an instance variable

Comment: "My NSMutableArray is allocated and initialized" - can you show where you do this? Because that would seem to be the issue here. Please include property declarations and initial setup code.

Comment: BTW diamonds (the array) is an instance variable

Comment: `if (levelNumber > 2 <= 4)` is that supposed to work? I haven't got an ObjectiveC compiler handy, but I would guess this translates to `if ((levelNumber > 2) <= 4)` which is always true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are first calling:

```
diamonds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

but later calling, for example:

```
diamonds = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", nil];
```

The second call will assign to `diamonds` an autoreleased object, you need to retain that object.

There is an inconsistency in your code in that with your first call you have an retained object as opposed to an autoreleased object in the second call.

Comment: ... not to mention a memory leak.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you're overreleasing the diamonds array, by other words, array object is already deallocated and you're trying to call a method for it. Use NSZombieEnabled=YES argument or Instruments with Zombies.

Comment: im not over releasing the array considering I've only released it once and thats in the dealloc method

Comment: In fact, you're under retaining it, which gets you with the same result of accessing random memory.

Answer (score 2):

Either do what ThomasW suggests and retain the new array (but this will leak your original instance) or simply add items into the array instead of creating a new one:

```
diamonds = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", nil];
```

Should read

```
[diamonds addObjectsFromArray:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", nil]];
```

This adds objects into an existing array instead of creating a new one.

You have already created the `diamonds` array with your `alloc/init`, you are recreating it as an autoreleased variable within your `if` statements.

The same applies to your `rocks` array.